# template_include for search.php makes Wordpress think its on the home page

Tags: search, tax-query, template-include

I have a custom tag-search feature, which allows people to search multiple tags to return relevant posts. Say they want to see posts that are tagged both 'Wordpress' and 'Tutorials'. I'm using the `template_include` filter, like so:

```
public static function template_redirect( $template ) {
    if( isset($_GET['tag-search']) )
    {
        $template = locate_template( array(
            'search.php',
            'archive.php',
            'index.php'
        ));
    }
    return $template;
}
```

the `tag-search` variable holds the name of the taxonomy, I check if it is set, thus indicating a search is being performed.

At this point `template` resolves to search.php, like it should. So that's good.

In the `pre_get_posts` action I add a `tax_query` to modify the returned posts to just the selected tags, and I set `is_search` to true, and `is_home` to false. Here is my `pre_get_posts` action:

```
public static function pre_get_posts($query) {
    if( !isset($_GET['tag-search']) || !isset($_GET['terms'])  ) return $query;

    if( strtolower( $_GET['method'] ) == 'and' )
    {
        $query->set( 'tax_query', array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $_GET['tag-search'],
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => explode(',', $_GET['terms']),
                'operator' => 'AND'
            )
        ) );
    }
    else
    {
        $query->set( 'tax_query', array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $_GET['tag-search'],
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => explode(',', $_GET['terms'])
            )
        ) );
    }
    $query->is_search = true;
    $query->is_home = false;
    return $query;
}
```

However, when I perform the search, the body class is 'home', and all of the `is_home` and `is_front_page` conditionals are **true**, which they shouldn't be, cause I just specifically stated I want this to be a search template right?

I know this can be done - when I add `&s` to the query string it works as it should - though it's a bit ugly that way. Any insights?

Comment: Post your `pre_get_posts` action

Comment: Updated to include the `pre_get_posts` action

Comment: Shaw, don't you should wrap all in a is_main_query() ?

Comment: Thanks I noticed that too while debugging it. Good catch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not resetting all the needed query variables, like `WP_Query::$is_page`, `WP_Query::$is_single` and `WP_Query::$is_archive`.

Also note that `'pre_get_posts'` is fired for all queries, the main and the secondaries, so you should check that you are working on the main query.

Finally, when you get data from `$_GET`you should sanitize it before to use it, a good way is to use [`filter_input()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) or [`filter_input_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php).

Your method should appear something like this:

```
public static function pre_get_posts($query)
{
    $data = filter_input_array(INPUT_GET, array(
        'tag-search' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
        'terms'      => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
        'method'     => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
    ));
    if( $query->is_main_query() && !empty($data['tag-search']) && !empty($data['terms']) ) {
        $query->init(); // this resets ALL vars
        $query->is_search = true;
        // set tax query array
        $tax_query = array(
            'taxonomy' => $data['tag-search'],
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => explode(',', $data['terms']),
        );
        // is AND method?
        if( strtolower( $data['method'] ) === 'and' ) {
            $tax_query['operator'] = 'AND';
        }
        // set tax query
        $query->set( 'tax_query', array($tax_query) );
    }
}
```

Doing so you do **not** need to filter the template (so you can remove your `template_redirect()` method): `search.php` will be loaded by WordPress because it will correctly recognize the query as a search.

---

PS: `'pre_get_post'` is an **action**, not a filter, so you **don't** need to return the query neither if you modify it.

Comment: Thanks, looks legit. Appreciate all the extra tips, you know your stuff. Will test and accept when I'm home!

Comment: Also, to add to your answer. We must also add `$query->is_singular = false`, and `$query->set('page_id', false)` in case it is called from a page.

Comment: @ShawnWernig if you really want to reset **all** query vars is better and easier to call `$query->init()`. Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
public static function pre_get_posts($query) {
    if( !isset($_GET['tag-search']) || !isset($_GET['terms'])  ) return $query;
        if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        if( strtolower( $_GET['method'] ) == 'and' )
        {
            $query->set( 'tax_query', array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => $_GET['tag-search'],
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => explode(',', $_GET['terms']),
                    'operator' => 'AND'
                )
            ) );
        }
        else
        {
            $query->set( 'tax_query', array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => $_GET['tag-search'],
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => explode(',', $_GET['terms'])
                )
            ) );
        }
        $query->set('s', '' );
        $query->is_search = true;
        $query->is_home = false;
    }
    return $query;
}
```

I added some extra checks and the 's' in a less ugly way